# c++ to vb.net, Couple conversion questsions

Tags: c++, vb.net, bitwise-operators

Ok, here's the function I'm a bit mystified by(Little rusty bitwise operators)

```
void two_one(unsigned char *in,int in_len,unsigned char *out)
{
unsigned char tmpc;
int i;

for(i=0;i<in_len;i+=2){
    tmpc=in[i];
    tmpc=toupper(tmpc);
    if((tmpc<'0'||tmpc>'9') && (tmpc<'A'||tmpc>'F'))tmpc='F';
    if(tmpc>'9')
        tmpc=toupper(tmpc)-'A'+0x0A;
    else
        tmpc-='0';
    tmpc<<=4; //Confused here
    out[i/2]=tmpc;

    tmpc=in[i+1];
    tmpc=toupper(tmpc);
    if((tmpc<'0'||tmpc>'9') && (tmpc<'A'||tmpc>'F'))tmpc='F';
    if(tmpc>'9')
         tmpc=toupper(tmpc)-'A'+0x0A;
    else
         tmpc-='0';

    out[i/2]|=tmpc; //Confused Here
}
}
```

I marked the two places that I don't quite understand.
If anyone could help me convert those pieces to Vb.Net, or at least help me understand what's going on there, that'd be awesome.

Thanks.

Update

So this is what I came up with, but it's not quite giving me back the right data...Anything look wrong here?

```
Public Function TwoOne(ByVal inp As String) As String
    Dim temp As New StringBuilder()
    Dim tempc As Char
    Dim tempi As Byte
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim len = inp.Length
    inp = inp + Chr(0)
    For i = 0 To len Step 2
        If (i = len) Then Exit For
        tempc = Char.ToUpper(inp(i))
        If ((tempc < "0"c Or tempc > "9"c) AndAlso (tempc < "A"c Or tempc > "F"c)) Then
            tempc = "F"c
        End If
        If (tempc > "9"c) Then
            tempc = Char.ToUpper(tempc)
            tempc = Chr(Asc(tempc) - Asc("A"c) + &HA)
        Else
            tempc = Chr(Asc(tempc) - Asc("0"c))
        End If
        tempc = Chr(CByte(Val(tempc)) << 4)
        Dim tempcA = tempc

        tempc = Char.ToUpper(inp(i + 1))
        If ((tempc < "0"c Or tempc > "9"c) AndAlso (tempc < "A"c Or tempc > "F"c)) Then
            tempc = "F"c
        End If
        If (tempc > "9"c) Then
            tempc = Char.ToUpper(tempc)
            tempc = Chr(Asc(tempc) - Asc("A"c) + &HA)
        Else
            tempc = Chr(Asc(tempc) - Asc("0"c))
        End If
        temp.Append(Chr(Asc(tempcA) Or Asc(tempc)))
    Next
    TwoOne = temp.ToString()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmpc <<= 4` shifts the bits in `tmpc` 4 places to the left, then assigns the value back to tmpc. Hence if `tmpc` was `00001101`, it becomes `11010000`

`out[i/2]|=tmpc` bitwise-ors the array value with `tmpc`. Hence if `out[i/2]` is `01001001` and `tmpc` is `10011010`, then `out[i/2]` becomes `11011011`

EDIT (updated question):
The lines `tmpc-='0';` in the original are not exactly the same as your new code `tempc = "0"c`. `-=` subtracts the value from the variable, and hence you need `tempc = tempc - "0"c` or similar

Comment: In VB.NET, you can use `Or` with two integral numbers to do a bitwise or. See [Logical and Bitwise Operators in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`tmpc<<=4;` (or `tmpc = tmpc << 4;`) shifts `tmpc` left by 4 bits.

`out[i/2]|=tmpc;` (or `out[i/2] = out[i/2] | tmpc;`) bitwise-ORs `out[i/2]` with `tmpc`.